# AngularJS View not updating ourside src

Tags: angularjs

In this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ut8cB2UPXUxLtGB7wZKZ/preview), the value edited is detected inside the src however the value outside src remains blank.

Select different radio buttons in the plnkr, the outside src does not update.

May I know why and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example of a case where an `ng-model` does not contain a `.` in it.

Here is the relevant plunker that solves the issue.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PsBuNmVxb4hqbjlxcOvx?p=preview)

```
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
  $scope.data = {
    filteringText : ''
  };

});
```

This happens because ng-include creates a new scope and because of the way prototypes work in javascript a primitive value in a child prototype overrides a primitive in the parent.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) if things are not clear in terms of prototypical inheritance.

**PS :** using `$parent` is not a good design. It tightly couples the view with the logic.

Comment: Thanks. The data.filteringText is a good idea than using $parent.filteringText.

Comment: That link is really helpful , and I need to go through it, as is your answer.

Comment: Agreed, better than my solution! I forgot how angular crawls up the scopes when it doesn't find the value in its own scope.

Comment: Coming back to this, how do I watch filteringText. `$scope.$watch('data.filteringText',...)` doesn't seem to be firing, even when the app loads.

Comment: Probably something wrong in my environment, [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tnb9Xw?p=preview) seems to work fine watching `filiteringText`

Answer (score 1):

This is because ng-include is creating its own scope, and the ng-model value you are assigning with the radio buttons is limited to that scope.

As such, your {{ filteringText }} in the main body has no idea that filteringText is being set with ng-model.

If we shift the content of your ng-include into the body, like so:

```
  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">


    <div ng-include src="'input.html'"></div>

  <input type="radio" ng-model="filteringText" value="">All
  <input type="radio" ng-model="filteringText" value="Add">Add
  <input type="radio" ng-model="filteringText" value="Edit">Edit
  <input type="radio" ng-model="filteringText" value="Delete">Delete
  </br>
    Outside src : {{filteringText}}
```

[Then we see that the outside src is updated, as we would expect, with the ng-model value.](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZb7koI5uy6dVagk1OCG?p=preview)

If we want to update a value in the main app scope from within the ng-include, we can use $parent.value inside your input.html file, like so:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.filteringText" value="">All
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.filteringText" value="Add">Add
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.filteringText" value="Edit">Edit
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.filteringText" value="Delete">Delete
<br/>
Inside src : {{$parent.filteringText}}
```

[And this will update your main body when you make changes inside ng-include.](http://plnkr.co/edit/sg14ZY1eMq2ve0a7W8bh?p=preview)