# AngularJS ng-click event not firing within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of tags built from a JSON object...

```
<div ng-repeat="comedian in comedians.details | orderBy: 'tag' | unique: 'tag'">
    <span ng-click="search = { tag: comedian.tag }">{{ comedian.tag }}</span>
</div>
```

And a list of images built from the same object...

```
<div ng-repeat="comedian in comedians.details | orderBy: 'name' | filter:search:strict">
    <img width="50" src="{{ comedian.image }}" alt="{{ comedian.name }}">
</div>
```

Both lists build as expected. But the click event is not firing to filter the images. If I manually build the list of tags like below the click event works...

```
<span ng-click="search = { tag: 'Character'}">Character</span>
<span ng-click="search = { tag: 'Sitcom'}">Sitcom</span>
```

But inside the ng-repeat they do not. Let me know if you need any other details! Thanks

Comment: Try scope' `$parent` : `<span ng-click="$parent.search = { tag: 'Sitcom'}">Sitcom</span>`

Comment: please, post your Json object

Comment: Adding $parent. worked! Thank you.

Comment: You welcome , and if you want to know **why** it is working , read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: Have a look at this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/19301144/1057639 ) . The problem is the same. You should probably understand how prototypical inheritance works. Also using `$parent` is the wrong way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Cherniv suggested in the first comment: use `$parent.search` so assing to the parent scope.

I'm mostly adding this as an answer so it can be accepted, since this question looks pretty unanswered at first sight, while it's actually solved.